# how to add the newly created conda interpreter to a specific project

Tags: python, development-environment

I wanted to import the `albumentations` package to run a deep learning task, but it has conflicts and failed when I tried to install it in the current environment, so I used `conda create --name` to create a new one, and in the new environment the `albumentations` package is installed successfully, but I can not find it in the python interpreter setting, and the project keeps showing "No module named 'albumentations' ", so , how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried create a new Base environment in the Setting-->Python Interpreter--> add --> Virtualenv Environment , and in the new Base environment, the newly created interpreter will appear below the Existing environment option.